# Python wrapping a function line to produce a virtual file for reading

Tags: python, io

I have an application I use which reads a large (non-ASCII)log file and is able to output the file to txt.  The application API has an 'export_to_txt' function where you can specify an output file.

I would normally produce the output txt file and then do a read through it for certain strings to pick out particular values of interest to drop into a spreadsheet, I would then delete the file after use.

The funtion to export to txt is shown below, but I was wondering if I could somehow wrap the ExportToTxt line to redirect the output to a list or other object so that I could 'virtually' scan the txt for the values I need rather than generating, opening, scanning and then deleting a txt file each time.  Is this even possible, i'm not so sure?

```
def export_to_txt(self, output_path, delimeter=','):
    if self.workgroup == None:
        raise RuntimeError('workgroup not set')
    value = self.workgroup.ExportToTxt(output_path, delimeter)
    if value == 0:
        raise RuntimeError('Failed to export to text file: %s' % self.application.Error)
```

Alternatively if I could generate both a virtual and physical file, work with the virtual file and then just delete the directory containing the physical files after processing all logs.

Thanks for reading,
MikG

Comment: Does `output_path` only take a string with a file path in it, or could you also pass a file-like object?

Comment: Does ExportToTxt accept StringIO or BytesIO objects? These can be substituted where a function accepts a file object.

Comment: Hi, The output_path only takes a string of a file path and not StringIO/BytesIO, else it complains of an incorrect path

Comment: Then you need an IO-level buffer/pipe. Are you linux or windows?

Comment: Hi mdurant, i'm using Windows 7